# Riverpod: performing two different depending actions after another

Tags: flutter, riverpod

My setup in flutter riverpod looks something like this:

1. A list view in which I can select objects to show them on a seperate page. This state is stored in the `selectedProvider` (a `StateProvider`).
2. A `StateNotifierProvider` (I will call it the `ObjectController`) which holds a list of all `objects`. It loads them on initialization from the database. Via methods I can create new `objects`.
3. A `StateNotifierProvider` (I will call it the `MessageController`) which watches the `selectedProvider`. As a state it holds a list of `messages` which it loads on initialization based on the selected `object`. Via methods I can add `messages` to the state.

Now I want to add new `objects` to my list view when the user presses a button.
This means I want to create it in the `ObjectController` and select it in the `selectedProvider`. This works perfectly fine because those two providers are independent:

```
void _onAddObject(
  ObjectController objectController,
  MessageController messageController,
  StateController<AsyncValue<Object?>> selectedProvider
) {
  selectedProvider.state = const AsyncLoading();

  try {
    // first we create a new object...
    final newObject = await journalController.createObject();

    // After that we select it. This is not a problem because the providers are independent.
    selectedProvider.state = newObject;
  } catch (err, st) {
    selectedProvider.state = AsyncError(err, st);
  }
}
```

Now I have the problem that I also want to initialize the newly created object **after** it was selected in the `selectedProvider` via the `MessageController` by calling a method `onObjectCreated()`. This should perform a initialization of the newly created and now `selectedObject` in the `MessageController`: in specific adding a single message to the before empty state. It is important that the `onObjectCreated()` is called after the object was selected and the `MessageController` has been updated so that it knows which object to update, it's ensured that its state is not loading anymore and that the newly added object is not lost after the state notifier is reloaded.

Who should be responsible for calling the method `onObjectCreated()` on the `MessageController`?

Note that objects can also be selected other times when it was not created directly before.

I thought about doing it in the `_onAddObject` method in the view. After the selection has been done. Then I am modifying a provider that has already `unmounted` because it was updated after performing the selection.
So something like this did not work:

```
// first we create a new object...
final newObject = await journalController.createObject();

// After that we select it. This is not a problem because the providers are independent.
selectedProvider.state = newObject;

// and now we initialize it
messageController.onObjectCreated();
```

Then I thought about doing it in the initialization of the `MessageController` because it would know when the new object has been created and when itself is fully initialized. I did not know how to differentiate between `objects` that were simply selected and objects that were just created.

I thought maybe I can encode the information in a bool that a newly object was just created in a seperate provider (or directly in the `selectedProvider`). This meant that I have to reset the boolean after it was created and initialized so that other updates of that provider would not lead to a new initialization. That lead to the error that providers are not allowed to modify other providers during their intialization.

Maybe the solution could be to not reset the boolean in that provider but none of it seems like a working and elegant solution.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Not enough time to give details, but the description tells me that you're thinking imperatively, and not reactively.  Flutter and Riverpod both work better when you are pulling state and not pushing state.  A watches B... B doesn't tell A what to do.  I hope that helps you understand your predicament.  Rewrite it as a dependency graph.